# Find if device is tilted left or right

Tags: javascript, mobile, orientation

I would like to find if a device, in landscape mode, is tilted left, right or not at all. Example:

Not at all:

[image]

Left:

[image]

Right:

[image]

I have looked at the `deviceorientation` API but found no clear way to find none, left or right. I would prefer to have it considered none if the phone is tilted only a small amount. It would be awesome if I could get a number for the rotation, positive if left, negative if right, 0 if none, but this is not required. I would also like a answer that has the most browser support possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The section "4.1 deviceorientation Event" of the [DeviceOrientation Eventdraft](https://w3c.github.io/deviceorientation/spec-source-orientation.html) says that

> Thus the angles alpha, beta and gamma form a set of intrinsic Tait-Bryan angles of type Z-X'-Y''.

AFAIU, what you want is convert that to [Z-X'-Z'' instrinsic Euler angels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles) and get the angle that represents the last rotation. Well, let's dust off 3D trigonometric skills and with help from quite useful [table in the Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles#Rotation_matrix) we can see that

```
spin = atan2(cos(beta)*sin(gamma), sin(beta))
```

or if we put it into some JS code

```js
window.addEventListener("deviceorientation", handleOrientation, true);
function handleOrientation(event) {
    // those angles are in degrees
    var alpha = event.alpha;  
    var beta = event.beta;
    var gamma = event.gamma;

    // JS math works in radians
    var betaR = beta / 180 * Math.PI;
    var gammaR = gamma / 180 * Math.PI;
    var spinR = Math.atan2(Math.cos(betaR) * Math.sin(gammaR), Math.sin(betaR));

    // convert back to degrees
    var spin = spinR * 180 / Math.PI;
}
```

Note that calculated as such `spin` is `0` when the device is in natural portrait orientation. And your landscape example corresponds to `-90` degrees.

[image: smartphone in "left" landscape orientation]

Beware also that [Orientation and motion data explained](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Orientation_and_motion_data_explained) MDN page says that

> **Warning**: Currently, Firefox and Chrome do not handle these coordinates the same way. Take heed when using them.

I tested my code only on iOS in Chrome. You can see a live demo at https://plnkr.co/edit/78IAUlbkQZMmogdlxGAH?p=preview. Note that you need to click on an icon "Launch the preview in a separate window" in the top-right of the preview area or it won't work because access to the `deviceorientation` API from iframe is prohibit at least on iOS.